# this method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, location, trusted

I have a word document written in an excel VBA program and then read in a Word VBA program. The directory is below a trusted set of directories which has "subfolders of this location are also trusted" ticked. Trust is set up in both the Excel and the Word VBA programs via the Options/Trust Center/Trust Center Settings/Trusted locations. I have also subsequently explicitly nominated the directory as trusted without solving the problem.

In the word VBA program I attempt to insert and adjust a logo .png file into the file but get the above message, and the file is, indeed, opened in read only as I can verify by attempting to modify it. If I save it under a different name it still remains read only, even though both files are in the same trusted directory.

The subroutine trying to modify the file is:

```
Sub InsertLogo(oDocument As Document)
'
' InsertLogo Macro
'
'
    oDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Select
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=Replace(sOutputFilePath & sColourFileName, Chr(34), "") _
        , LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.InlineShapes(1).Height = CentimetersToPoints(1.35)
    Selection.InlineShapes(1).Width = CentimetersToPoints(2.38)
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    
End Sub
```

The MoveLeft command is the one giving the error.

These programs were originally written in Office 2010 and worked successfully in previous years. but last year I upgraded to Office 2016.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Written properly, you code would not use Select, Selection, or MoveLeft. See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/drawing-and-graphics/49547-automate-insertion-multiple-images-into-document-all.html. As it is, your unqualified references to Selection mean your macro is referencing whatever tour Excel selection is - and Excel's Selection methods.

Comment: Thanks, @Macropod. I am not sure I understand. the first line of the routine selects a table element of the document passed as a parameter. it all seems explicit to me. Am I missing something? In addition, if I access the document written in the prior Excel VBA program directly in Windows before running this Word VBA program it is clearly saved in read only mode even though the directory in which it is saved is trusted. I think this is the source of my problem. When it tries to edit the document in the code shown it fails because the document is read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, without selecting anything:

```
Sub InsertLogo(oDocument As Document, sOutputFilePath As String, sColourFileName As String)
With oDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range
  .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=Replace(sOutputFilePath & sColourFileName, Chr(34), ""), _
        LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=.Duplicate
  With .InlineShapes(1)
    .Height = CentimetersToPoints(1.35)
    .Width = CentimetersToPoints(2.38)
  End With
  .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
End With
End Sub
```

Note that I've also adjusted the code to pass the sOutputFilePath & sColourFileName variables to it also.

Comment: I have largely replaced the InsertLogo as you suggested (the added argumernts were defined as global entities.)

Comment: the problem was that the word documents written in the Excel VBA program were written as read-only and therefore could not be modified in the Word VBA program. However, after persisting for several days, I woke up this morning to find the word docs were no longer being written as read-only. Everything worked. The only thing I can think of is that the system was rebooted over night (I usually Hibernate) and the change to trust settings needed a reboot to activate. Anyway, thanks for your help,@macropod. I have gone run the process several times (about 20 min each time) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Your read-only problem was most likely due to your code leaving orphaned instances of Word running with the document(s) open. Regardless, your original code could not have worked for the reasons I gave.